# update error - Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table posts that has two columns "share_inst", "share_tw" as tinyints and by default they are "0".

I have a form that allows a admin of the post to select if we wants that a post can be shared in all sites or just one or none. But its not working.

When I select the sites and click in "Update" I get the error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

Also in the form the checkboxes are not appearing checked if in database the columns "share_inst" and "share_tw" and "1".

Do you know where is the error?

**Form**:

```
<form method="post" {{route('posts.share.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputName">
                   Select which sites the post can be shared</label>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="share_tw" id="share_tw" value="share_tw"
                            {{ $post->share_tw == 0 ? 'checked' : '' }} {{ $post->share_tw == 0 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                        Twiiter
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="share_inst" id="share_inst" value="share_inst"
                            {{ $post->share_inst == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }} {{ $post->share_inst == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                        Instagram
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
        </form>
```

**Update method:**

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->share_tw = $request->share_tw;
        $post->share_ins = $request->share_ins;
        $post->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

**Routes:**

```
// update shared
Route::get('post/edit/{id}/share',    [ 'uses' => 'ShareController@edit', 'as'=>'posts.share.edit']);
Route::post('post/update/{id}/share', [ 'uses' => 'ShareController@update', 'as'=>'posts.share.update']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing) add `method_field('PATCH')` to form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('posts.share.update', ['post_id' => $post])}}">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
</form>
```

Comment: would you share the code of route definition  for this method ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
Route::put('post/update/{id}/share', [ 'uses' => 'ShareController@update', 'as'=>'posts.share.update']);
```

Comment: Also you need to keep csrf and patch in form as suggested by Mehdi

Comment: That means its not reaching controller. The error is generating from the form. First try with static form value for each and see if result is saved. Then work on the form

Comment: One more thing, the value in form should be like `value="{{ $post->share_tw }}"` and `value="{{ $post->share_inst }}"`